# Arduino Nano PWM frequency

Tags: pwm

I have been using an Arduino Nano as a PWM controller for a heating element.

I am currently using **D11** (PB3). I could change, although all pins with PWM are in use, and would require a re-write and re-wire.

This produces a signal at ~490Hz, but I would like to experiment with changing this to a higher frequesncy.

I gather it its possible to vary the frequency by changing the divisor from its default 64.

My sketch uses Uses http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SevenSegmentLibrary and calls millis() - will changing PWM divisor impact on either of these?

NOTE I have read the `setPwmFrequency` documentation, but find "disrupts the normal operation" unhelpful - I am actually after some explanation of the concrete effect. I only use `millis()` to time button presses and flash a LED, which are not time critical

*Please keep in mind that changing the PWM frequency changes the Atmega's timers and disrupts the normal operation of many functions that rely on time (delay(), millis(), Servo library).*

I have been doing some further study. http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency states  *Changes on pins 3, 5, 6, or 11 may cause the delay() and millis() functions to stop working.*

Other references say 3, 11 use `timer 2` so **do they affect `millis()` or not** as other references claim `timer 0` is used for these.

Comment: Yes and no, depending on the pwm timer used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where this misinformation comes from... The answer is
**no**, reconfiguring Timer 2 does **not** affect `millis()` nor
`delay()`, as these functions rely on Timer 0. AFAIK the Arduino core
does not use Timer 2 at all. But note that there may be other Arduino or
third party libraries that rely on Timer 2.

You can see here the [source code of `millis()` and
`delay()`](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c).

As MITU RAJ correctly states in his answer, the PWM signal on pin 11 is
provided by Timer 2, so you can use it safely.

Comment: The misinformation comes from http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency. I am sure I am not the only user to have been mislead. The other answer just published an extract of the misleading documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the pin you used for the PWM.

***Arduino UNO/NANO specs say following things:***

The base frequency for pins 3, 9, 10, and 11 is 31250 Hz.

The base frequency for pins 5 and 6 is 62500 Hz.

The divisors available on pins 5, 6, 9 and 10 are: 1, 8, 64, 256, and 1024.

The divisors available on pins 3 and 11 are: 1, 8, 32, 64, 128, 256, and 1024.

PWM frequencies are tied together in pairs of pins. If one in a pair is changed, the other is also changed to match.

Pins 5 and 6 are paired on timer0.

Pins 9 and 10 are paired on timer1.

Pins 3 and 11 are paired on timer2.

**Changes on pins 3, 5, 6, or 11 may cause the delay() and millis() functions to stop working. Other timing-related  functions may also be affected.**

Comment: Since you're quoting the specs, it'd be nice if you could also link to them? :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **NO**, changing the PWM divider for pin 11 will not affect the `millis()` function (nor `delay()`).

---

**Explanation:**
The [Arduino Nano](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-nano) uses the ATMega328P microcontroller, same as the [Arduino Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3).

Pin 11's PWM is controlled by Timer 2. By default Timer 2 has a prescale of 64 (ie. setting 0x04). The base frequency of Timer 2 is 31372.55 Hz resulting in a frequency of 490.2 Hz (ie. 31372.55/64 = 490.1961).

On the other hand, the microsecond timer (ie. the one used by `millis()`, `micros()`, `delay()` and `delayMicroseconds()`) is controlled by Timer 0.

So changing the prescaler of Timer 2 will not affect `millis()`.

It will however change the PWM frequency of Pin 3.

---

**Back to your question:**
The possible PWM frequencies of Pin 11 (higher than 488 Hz) are:

31373 / 32 = 980.4 Hz
31373 / 8 = 3921.6 Hz
31373 / 1 = 31373 Hz

Where 32, 8, 1 are the prescaler.
Which equates to a setting value of 0x03, 0x02 & 0x01 respectively.

Add this line of code:

```
TCCR2B = TCCR2B & 0b11111000 | setting;
```

Where `setting` is the value of the setting for the respective prescaler.

```
============================================  
|| Frequency [Hz] || Prescaler || Setting ||  
============================================  
|| 31373.55       || 1         || 0x01    ||  
|| 3921.57        || 8         || 0x02    ||  
|| 980.39         || 32        || 0x03    ||  
|| 490.20         || 64        || 0x04    ||  
|| 245.10         || 128       || 0x05    ||  
|| 122.55         || 256       || 0x06    ||  
|| 30.64          || 1024      || 0x07    ||  
============================================
```

Source code: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/wiring.c

Comment: Just nitpicking but... the timer's base frequency in phase correct PWM mode is F\_CPU/510 (31373 Hz), not F\_CPU/512: it takes 255 cycles to count from 0 to 255, then 255 more to count back to zero. C.f. the equation for the PWM frequency in the datasheet.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Good point. The answer has now been corrected.

Comment: would it be possible to go down a step slower to 15.31 HZ?